# ObservableCollection Refresh is not working, when dynamic allocated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
public ObservableCollection<Model.ChildCommand> ChildCommands { get; private set; }
```

ChildCommands is bound to a Datagrid.

Both Segments show me the items in the Datagrid.

But in Segment one the Datagrid items doesn't refresh automatically when the collection changes.
With Segment two, the refresh works.

Segment 1:

```
var childs = from child in m_context.ChildCommand.Local
                         select child;


this.ChildCommands = new ObservableCollection<Model.ChildCommand>(childs);
```

Segment 2:

```
this.ChildCommands = m_context.ChildCommand.Local;
```

How do I get the automatic refresh by using Segment one?

Comment: What kind of UI are you using? WPF or WinForms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for Segment 1 not updating automatically is that you end up binding to a different ObservableCollection instance.

When m_context.ChildCommand.Local changes, your Segment 2 datagrid gets notified because it is bound to that observable collection instance. However your Segment 1 datagrid is bound to a different observable collection instance (that you yourself create when you say new ObservableCollection(childs).

If you truly want both of them to be bound to the m_context.ChildCommand.Local observable collection then you should implement it as such instead of creating a different observable collection instance for Segment 1.

Comment: ChildCommands = from child in m_context.ChildCommand.Local    select child;   //// This does not work, do you have an idea how to solve my Problem?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the `ChildCommands` property, as such:

```
public class YourClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      private ObservableCollection<Model.ChildCommand> _childCommands;

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      public ObservableCollection<Model.ChildCommand> ChildCommands
      {
          get { return _childCommands; }
          set
          {
              _childCommands= value;
              OnPropertyChanged("ChildCommands");
          }
      }

      protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
          }
      }
  }
```

See this for more info: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

my solution to this is to inherit my class from the NotificationObject class.

After that, just use

```
this.ChildCommands = m_context.ChildCommand.Local;

RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ChildCommands); //this line notifies the UI that the underlying property has changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Bindings to a collection will not be updated if the collection gets re-instantiated. You have two options:

1. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the ChildCommands property
2. Instead of doing:

   this.ChildCommands = new ObservableCollection(childs);

Do this instead:

```
this.ChildCommands.Clear();

foreach(var child in childs)
   this.ChildCommands.Add(child);
```